# jQuery slideUp/Down strange events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have created a navbar that slides up and down whether your house is hovering on a bar or not.

The problem is that the `<a>` elements inside the navbar are flashing and moving when your mouse is in certain positions, can anyone please explain why this is happening and what the error is, and possibly a solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/xm4uLkg1/

Thanks, Lachlan.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$(".navbar ul li a").fadeOut(200);` this will set the  css property to `display:none;`.

Now, what happens is when you call `$(this).fadeTo(200, 1);` it will only make one `<a>` tag to get in view which will take different position as other is `display:none` still yet and `ul` gives full space to only displayed `li a` tag so it changes location

To get over of this issue you can do this

```
            window.onload = function() {
              $(".navbar ul li a").fadeOut(200);
              $(".navbar").slideUp("medium");
           };
           $(".navbar ul li a").mouseenter(function() {
              $(".navbar ul li a").fadeTo(200, 1);//This will set all a tags in vew
          });
          $(".navbar ul li a").mouseleave(function() {
            $(".navbar ul li a").fadeTo(100, 0.8); //This will set all a tags in view
          });
          $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#wrap").mouseenter(function() {

               $(".navbar ul li a").fadeIn(100);
               $(".navbar").stop().slideDown("fast");
             });
             $("#wrap").mouseleave(function() {

               $(".navbar ul li a").fadeOut(200);
               $(".navbar").slideUp("medium");
             });
          });
```

Comment: this doesn't help as the error (the <a> flashing and coming down when the bar isn't down) is still occuring and this makes all buttons change opacity at once. Thanks anyway